# php try catch correct usage

Tags: php, try-catch

I am trying to learn some more PHP oop stuff -

I found the code block below on here...

I am passing in "PC" to the constructor which triggers the "Invalid Platform" exception - it is caught by the try catch block I have added, but then calling `printCode` gives an "undefined index" error which I expected as "PC" is not in the array `platformArray`..

My question is what is the correct way to handle all these exceptions/errors? Should you have a try catch block for every function??

```
<?php
include('Logger.php');

class Platform
{
    private static $platformArray = array (
        'ps3'  => array ('displayName' => 'playstation 3', 'function' => 'funcPS3'),
        'xbox' => array ('displayName' => 'Xbox', 'function' => 'funcXbox')
    );
    private        $type;

    public function __construct($log, $type)
    {
        try {
            if (!array_key_exists($type, self::$platformArray)) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Platform type $type");
            }
            $this->type = $type;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $log->write_error_log("0", "good_bad_code1.php", $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function printCode()
    {
        // This was a question embedded within your question, you can use
        // http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php
        // and pass an instance with a method name.
        return call_user_func(array ($this, self::$platformArray[$this->type]));
    }

    private function funcPS3()
    {
        echo 'ps3 specific code';
    }

    private function funcXbox()
    {
        echo 'xbox specific code';
    }
}
```

Comment: Catching the exception immediately right after you've thrown it is extremely pointless. Get rid of the `try..catch` inside `__construct`; put it somewhere else where catching the exception actually makes sense, somewhere around where you're calling `new Platform('PC')`.

Comment: throwing an Exception and catching at the same time is... unusual. More likely, what you'd want is to have your object instantiation inside a `try`/`catch` block, since you know creating that object may trigger an exception. But if you catch it immediately, throwing the exception makes no sense, it's just a convoluted `if`.

Comment: ok thanks ... so best practice is something like:  try { $o=new ob(); } catch{ } ?

Comment: Yes. The point of exceptions is that they travel back up the call chain and can alert callers higher up that something went belly up. Let whoever has a useful fallback plan catch and handle the exception. If there is no valid alternative plan (e.g. database connection doesn't work… what now?) then don't catch the exception at all.